# How to create blanktemplate or remove existed template in ADXportal (Adx styudio) development

Tags: visual-studio, dynamic, content-management-system, dynamics-crm-4

How to remove adxportal default templates? 
I want a portal without having any template . Using adxporta. online and offline development

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the steps for creating a new Template in ADX.
http://community.adxstudio.com/products/adxstudio-portals/documentation/developers-guide/getting-started/adding-a-page-template/